# Scope issue in Javascript with setTimeout

Tags: javascript, scope

Scope issue, I thought function statements were always hoisted to the top of the current context. So why is 'hideNav()' undefined in the following?

```
var t;


function showNav(bflag){
clearTimeout(t);
if(bflag===true){
    $("#tS2").stop(false,false).animate({
                'bottom':'0'
            }, 1000);
}else{

    t=setTimeout("hideNav()",1000);

}
}

function hideNav(){
$("#tS2").stop(true,false).animate({
                'bottom':'-125px'
            }, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change,

```
setTimeout("hideNav()",1000);
```

to

```
setTimeout(hideNav, 1000);
```

`hideNav` is only defined in the current context, but you are passing a string to `setTimeout`. That string will be eval'd when the timeout occurs in the context of the global object. Since your `hideNav` function is not defined in the global object, it will throw an exception.

By directly passing a reference to the function to `setTimeout`, you don't have to worry about it.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a string with `setTimeout()` in this case.

Change it to:

```
t = setTimeout(hideNav, 1000);
```

Using a string with `setTimeout()` forces it to use `eval()` to evaluate your string and when it does that, it uses the global context, not your local context.  So, my guess is that `hideNav()` isn't actually a global function (you probably have this code wrapped inside some other function).

Besides, it's ALWAYS better to use a direct function reference rather than a string and a lot faster too.  Just remember when you use the direct function reference, do NOT put the parentheses afterwards.  You want a reference to the function, you don't want to immediately execute it and pass the return value which is what it would do if you used `t = setTimeout(hideNav(), 1000);`